# Squeezing the gap r basic plot with different levels of y axis

Tags: r

I want to squeeze (narrow the gap) between the yellow line and the rest of the graph in the basic r plot through having different levels of y-axis labels. How can I do that?

[image]

my code is as follows:

```
Site <- subset(data, Sites == "Bx")

plot(SiteB$value,xlim = c(1,18),ylim=c(4,99.5),xlab="",ylab="",lwd=2,type = "n", asp = NA)
lines(SiteB$value,SiteB$A,type="l", col="orange",lwd=2)
lines(SiteB$value,SiteB$D, type="l", col="purple",lwd=2)
lines(SiteB$value,SiteB$G,type="l", col="blue",lwd=2)
lines(SiteB$value,SiteB$L,type="l",col="red",lwd=2)
lines(SiteB$value,SiteB$M,type="l", col="black",lwd=2)
#lines(SiteB$value,SiteB$S, type="l", col="magenta",lwd=2)
lines(SiteB$value,SiteB$T,type="l",col="green",lwd=2)
```

Comment: The right answer is probably *don't* do this, but if you must I would do two separate plots with different y-axes and join them with ```par(mfrow)``` or ```cowplot```.

Comment: @geoff, thank you for your constructive comment but I want them together for comparison purposes. But, I want to cut off the gap (the range)  between those graphs and the above (orange color) one.

Comment: Yep, I understand the idea. I'm suggesting you make one plot with the lines at the bottom with a Y axis of maybe 0-20, and second plot with only the orange line with a Y axis of 80-100 and then compose them into a single image with ```par(mfrow)``` or ```cowplot```.

Comment: Use `log='y'` in `plot()`, i.e. use logarithmic y-axis.

Comment: @jay.sf, you mean , I use log for all y values?

Comment: No, just add the argument to `plot` call. `plot(SiteB$value, ..., log='y')`.

Comment: @jay.sf, I added the log argument, but it doesn't bridge the gap between the other graph lines and the orange line.